# Carousel Won't Automatically Slide

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the owl carousel on http://www.mjluxepromotions.com/new-site

Everything works until I try to make it slide automatically. Sometimes it even smashing the slides together.

According to the Owl Carousel documentation located here http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

The following piece of JavaScript should do the job. I added it to the footer but it's not working.

```
<script>
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({

// Most important owl features

//Autoplay
autoPlay : 3000,
stopOnHover : false
)}
</script>
```

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should check your console, you have multiple errors that need fixing.

Comment: Might need to wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` so it doesn't trigger before DOM loads.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you closed out the function incorrectly:

```
)} //Parenthesis Bracket
```

Should be:

```
}); // Bracket Parenthesis
```

Answer (score 0):

**AutoPlay is a bool type, so you can use true if you want to make it auto on page load, or false if you want manual click,**

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({

//Autoplay
autoPlay : true,
stopOnHover : false

})
```